# Exoplayer battery consumption for audio playback in media3-exoplayer:1.2.0

Tags: java, android, exoplayer

to reduce battery consumption `ExoPlayer` introduced support for audio offload in 2.12 as an experimental feature.
This function is no longer available in the media3 library for the current `Exoplayer` version 1.2.0.
I cannot find anything about this in the documentation. Is there another way to reduce the battery consumption for audio playback?

Thanks
GGK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's still there: 
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/exoplayer/track-selection#audioOffload

```
val audioOffloadPreferences =
  AudioOffloadPreferences.Builder()
      .setAudioOffloadMode(AudioOffloadPreferences.AUDIO_OFFLOAD_MODE_ENABLED)
      // Add additional options as needed
      .setIsGaplessSupportRequired(true)
      .build()
player.trackSelectionParameters =
  player.trackSelectionParameters
    .buildUpon()
    .setAudioOffloadPreferences(audioOffloadPreferences)
    .build()
```